# Get ActualHeight/ActualWidth from Contentpresenter

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, binding, custom-controls

I've got this `XAML` Code and I tried accessing the `Width`/`Height` of the `Contentpresenter` which was `NaN`. After that I did some research and found out that I need to get `FrameworkElement.ActualWidth` and `FrameworkElement.ActualHeight` but I cant access them. The values for them are `{{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}}`

Here is the `XAML` (btw: it's a custom control):

```
   <local:MultiBindingConv
        x:Key="MultiBindingConv" />
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CADViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate
                    TargetType="{x:Type local:CADViewer}">
               <ContentPresenter Name="CadContent" Content="{Binding VisualContainer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                     <i:EventTrigger
                                        EventName="SizeChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                                            Command="{Binding ContentSizeChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                           <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingConv}">
                                 <Binding ElementName="CadContent" Path="FrameworkElement.ActualWidth"/>
                                 <Binding ElementName="CadContent" Path="FrameworkElement.ActualHeight"/>
                              </MultiBinding>
                           </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                     </i:EventTrigger>
                  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
               </ContentPresenter>
               <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding VisualContainer.ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>-->
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: After the user changes the size of the window I'll call the delegate `ContentSizeChanged`. This delegate points to a method which has width and height as parameters. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to:

```
    <ControlTemplate
                TargetType="{x:Type local:CADViewer}">
           <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
           <ContentPresenter Name="CadContent" Content="{Binding VisualContainer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger
                                    EventName="Loaded">
                       <i:InvokeCommandAction
                                        Command="{Binding CtrlLoaded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                 <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:EventToCommandBehavior
                            Command="{Binding ContentSizeChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Event="SizeChanged"
                            PassArguments="True" />
                 </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
              </ContentPresenter>
           </Border>
           <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding VisualContainer.ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>-->
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Now I get the eventargs and can access the `ActualHeight` with: `e.Source.ActualHeight`